# $C[0,1]$ is Banach-space isomorphic to $c_0(C[0,1])$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, banach-spaces, banach-algebras

$c_0(C[0,1])$ is the $c_0$-direct sum of countably many $C[0,1]$.How to prove

$C[0,1]$ is Banach-space isomorphic to $c_0(C[0,1])$.

Here,Banach-space isomorphism means a bounded invertible operator from $C[0,1]$ onto $c_0(C[0,1])$.

Comment: Is Banach-space isomorphic the term you want? Ordinarily I think of "Banach-space isomorphic" as synonymous with isometrically isomorphic.

Comment: @ToddTrimble I think (but I don't claim to speak for everyone) that "Banach-space isomorphic" is in contrast to "Banach-algebraically isomorphic" (both objects are Cstar algebras, so if one just said "isomorphic", one might think this is isomorphism of Cstar algebras)

Comment: @ToddTrimble As I think was discussed on the nLab a while ago, "isometrically isomorphic" is not usually used as the default by people who work with Banach spaces - if we want isometric we usually feel obliged to explicitly mention it

Comment: @YemonChoi (Referring to your second comment) I defer to your judgment here, although I've seen "linearly homeomorphic" also used to indicate the weaker notion of isomorphism (and FWIW, I personally believe that would be preferable language).

Comment: In Banach space theory, isomorphism means linear homeomorphism. This is completely standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a useful simple

**Lemma.** If $X\sim X\oplus X$, $Y\sim Y\oplus Y$, and each of $X,Y$ is isomorphic to a complemented subspace of another, then $X\sim Y$.

**Proof.** We have $X\sim Y\oplus A$, then $X\sim (Y\oplus Y)\oplus A=Y\oplus(Y\oplus A)=Y\oplus X$, analogously $Y\sim X\oplus Y$.

Now let $X=C([0,1])$, $Y=c_0(X)$. Property $Y\sim Y\oplus Y$ is clear, property $X\sim X\oplus X$ follows from $X\oplus X=C([0,1]\times \{0,1\})$ and Milyutin theorem. $X$ is clearly complemented in $Y$. At last, $Y$ is the space of functions on the compact space on the plane $K=\cup \{\frac1n \times [0,\frac1n]\}\cup (0,0)$, which are equal to 0 at $(0,0)$. Again by Milyutin theorem we see that $X\sim C(K)$, hence $Y$ is isomorphic to a hyperplane in the space isomorphic to $X$. Hyperplane is of course complemented.

This is maybe not a very good proof, since your claim may be used in the proof of Milyutin theorem (I do not remember). But if so, study the proof, it should contain this claim.

Comment: @FedorPetrov.What is "A" in the proof of the lemma above?

Comment: Complement subspace.

Comment: @FedorPetrov.Thank you for help. I am confused at the statement of your lemma. Do you mean that if $X\sim X\oplus X, Y\sim \oplus Y$, "Then" each of $X,Y$ is isomorphic to a complemented subspace of another?

Comment: No, it is another assumption. Sorry, I forgot to formulate the conclusion, fixed now.

Comment: oh, I see. thank you. $Y=\{f\in C(K)| f(0,0)=0\}$. I can chek this statemet by building an isometric isomorphism. But is there any easier way to see this?

Comment: What may be easier?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36222/discussion-between-li-jingyang-and-fedor-petrov).

Comment: Fedor, you don't need Milutin's theorem. To see that $C[0,1]$ is isomorphic to $C[0,1]$, consider the subspaces of functions that vanish on $[1/2,1]$ and vanish on $[0,1/2]$ to see that the $\infty$-direct sum of two hyperplanes in $C[0,1]$ is (even isometrically)  isomorphic to a hyperplane in $C[0,1]$. The space $C[0,1]$ is isomorphic to its hyperplanes because, for example, it contains a complemented subspace isomorphic to $c_0$.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean $c_0(X)=\lbrace (x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N} \in X^{\mathbb N}: \|x_n\|_X\to 0\rbrace$ with norm $\|(x_n)_n\|=\sup\lbrace \|x_n\|_X: n\in\mathbb N\rbrace$, then $c_0(C[0,1])$ and $C[0,1]$ are isomorphic (as explained by Fedor) but not isometrically isomorphic: The unit ball of $C[0,1]$ has extreme points but that of $c_0(C[0,1])$ does not.